# Python - Separate thread for receiving messages

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a problem concerning threading in python (2.7.8). The problem resides in a python "chat" code written (I'll include the code to my threading class and my client class (different python files), since I think the problem is in one of those two, and not in the server code). When I run the Client.py file, I am able to communicate with another client (running the same python code) through a server, but the problem is that I have to refresh the .send_payload(msg) command in order to receive the message that the other client has sent (or simply by pressing enter in the chat, and hence sending "" as message). I want to know if it is possible to receive messages without "refreshing" the chat, somehow through threading.

```
class MessageReceiver(Thread):
      def __init(self,client,connection):
          Thread.__init__(self)
          self.daemon = True
          self.client = client
          self.connection = connection
          self.stop = False

      def run(self):
          while not self.stop:
              data = self.connection.recv(8192)
              if not data:
                   break
              else:
                   self.client.receive_message(data)
          pass




class Client:
    def __init__(self, host, server_port):
            self.host = host
            self.server_port = server_port
            self.connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.run()

    def run(self):
            self.connection.connect((self.host, self.server_port))
            self.thread = MessageReceiver(self, self.connection)
            self.thread.start()

            while True:
                text = raw_input()
                if(text.find("login") == 0):
                    data={"request":"login","content":text[text.find("login")+6:]}
                    self.send_payload(data)
                if(text.find("names") == 0):
                    data={"request":"names","content":""}
                    self.send_payload(data)
                else:
                    data={"request":"msg","content":text}
                    self.send_payload(data)

    def disconnect(self):
        self.thread.stop = True
        self.connection.close()
        print("Disconnected")

    def receive_message(self, message):
        print("Msg: " + message)

    def send_payload(self, data):
        self.connection.send(json.dumps(data))
        print("Payload sent!")
```

Comment: The code looks okay to me. May be its the server that is not relaying you the message? Might help if you post server's code.

Comment: That might be a little problematic considering the server code is 270 lines long. Do you have anything specific in mind why I have to refresh the chat in order to receive incoming messages?